# Image src.bind in a loop gives a 404

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have this view :

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li repeat.for="app of apps" class="list-group-item ${app.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
        <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail" src.bind="app.icon">
    </li>
</ul>
```

The VM  :

```
apps=[
  {
    id:getId(),
    routename:'config',
    name:'Configuration',
    icon:'parametres.png'
  },
  {
    id:getId(),
    routename:'import',
    name:'Import',
    icon:'../static/images/import.png'
  },
  {
    id:getId(),
    routename:'stats',
    name:'Statistiques',
    icon:'../static/images/parametres.png'
  }
];
```

So as you can guess I try to have my `src` attribute set dynamically. 
`parametres.png` is in `src` folder and other images are up one time and then in `static/images` folder (I have tried different paths).

The images never show in the browser:

[image: li field ...]

Console logs :
[image: console logs]

and :

[image: Network view]

I'm new to Aurelia/Javascript but I understand that webpack should do something to pictures before you can see them in your app, and in this case for some reason it doesn't do the job, so my pictures cannot be seen.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I don't think webpack can process your images like this, can you change your apps array to have the images imported, like this: icon:require('./parametres.png') ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to let webpack know in advance that you are going to load those images.

```
import parametersImg from "parametres.png";

...

    icon: parametersImg
...
```

FYI:
you have a little typo:
parametres => parameters

Answer (score 0):

With these suggestions I found a sort of a roundabout :

```
var parametres_png= require("./parametres.png");
...
apps = [
    {
      id: getId(),
      routename: 'config',
      name: 'Configuration',
      icon: parametres_png,
      backgroundColor:'rosybrown'
    },
...
```

@avrahamcool : no typo ;), just that I'm french so sometimes files names are in french .... Anyway Thanks for noticing it, It could have been an Typo :)

Thanks for your time and answers.